# LDAP search fails for certain characters on some attributes

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
(|(mail=andrew*)(cn=andrew*)(sn=andrew*)(telephoneNumber=andrew*))
```

i.e. it takes a search term from a UI and looks for a match against term* across a bunch of attributes.

The user enters andrew in this case and the app adds the wildcard. If the user enters andrew` (trailing back tick) the app looks for andrew`*.

I've noticed that if telephoneNumber is included in the searched attributes the query fails with a javax.naming.InvalidAttributeValueException, if it's excluded then the query works without error.

I'm not particularly interested in the backtick alone, but as it's not a special character in LDAP searches I'm wondering why I get this behaviour and if other characters will produce similar results. Is there going to be something in the schema that explains this if I can figure out how to query it, or will it be something else?

If it matters, accessing via a Spring library in a Java app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query probably fails because of attribute value constraints on the telephoneNumber attribute. The syntax for telephoneNumber attributes is described in [this RFC](https://docs.ldap.com/specs/rfc4517.txt). Back tick does indeed seem to be an invalid character in telephoneNumber values.

Now, I might be wrong, but reading your question it appears you are trying to construct filters using string concatenation. Please note that you should **never**, ever build queries of any sort using string concatenation, especially when parts of the queries come from user input. I'm sure you know this is the case for SQL queries, and it's equally true when you're using LDAP.

Spring LDAP provides two ways to help you build LDAP queries. The preferred approach is the use the LDAP query API documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#basic-queries) and (advanced usage) [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#query-builder-advanced). The old deprecated - but still functioning - way to do it is using the filter classes, documented in the old reference documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/basic.html#basic-filters).

Using these utilities you won't need to keep track of which characters need to be encoded and when. You also eliminate any risk for query injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, this looks spot on. The deprecated API looks to be the one in use, which may explain why this isn't being handled already?

Comment: In this particular case you need to be careful anyway because the back tick is not valid at all when matching against telephoneNumber. This is **not** handled by the library, since the best we could do anyway would be to throw a similar exception if attribute syntax is violated. The library handles escaping of unsafe characters only. For these types of attributes you will need to sanitise input anyway, which will definitely be a pain in general, but for telephone numbers you could easily replace all non-numeric characters with spaces and use the WhitespaceWildcardsFilter.